# How to convert image class to file

Tags: image, file, flutter, dart

I am actually trying to convert an image to a File with flutter. More precisely, I want to copy an image with the following code :

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final path = join(
            // Store the picture in the temp directory.
            // Find the temp directory using the `path_provider` plugin.
            (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
            '${DateTime.now()}.png',
          );

          final File localImage = await theImage.copy('path');

          //convert our Image file to bytes
          final bytes = await localImage.readAsBytes();
          MyImage myImage = MyImage(
              isLiked: false,
              imgBase64: base64Encode(bytes),
          );

),
```

But there is this error :

```
The method copy isn't defined for the clas 'Image'.
```

Is there a function like `Image.file(File file)` (which creates a widget that displays an ImageStream obtained from a File) to get a file from an Image ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Where is theImage coming from(as in gallery, web, camera)? Are you just trying to save the image locally?

Comment: What data type is `theImage`?

Comment: I try to save images in a database so I convert them to base64 and decod them with  `Image.memory(base64Decode(imgBase64))`. The type is `Image` but maybe there are others way to decode base64 to get a file and it would be easier to manage such images ?